# Formatting Moments.js to show date in a format not today, tomorrow etc

Tags: jquery, momentjs

I have the code below that adds days to the selected date, I would like that if the selected date is 25/04/2014 and i add two or three days using moments.js it should say for two days, 27/04/2014 instead of Sunday at 1.16pm.

Here is the code

```
  $('#no_of_days').focusout(function(){
        days= parseInt($(this).val());
        new_date = moment().add('d', days).calendar();
        $('#date_of_result').val(new_date);
    })
```

Answer (score 0):

This is easily found [in the documentation](http://momentjs.com/docs).  With a library like moment, I urge you to read the entirety of the documentation.  It's *really* important.

```
new_date = moment().add('d', days).format("DD/MM/YYYY");
```

or better yet, using the localization of the current user and language settings:

```
new_date = moment().add('d', days).format("L");
```